# How many way ,we can show $(e^x)'=e^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, education, reference-works

It is famous enough that $f(x)=\exp(x) \to f'(x)=f(x)$ . For example we can show it by taylor series like below :
$$\quad{e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+...\\
(e^x)'=0+1+\frac{2x}{2!}+\frac{3x^2}{3!}+\frac{4x^3}{4!}+\frac{5x^4}{5!}+...(\text{simplify})\\(e^x)'=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+...=e^x}$$
or by definition we have:
$$\quad{\large e=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{1}{\Delta x}}\\
e^x=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{x}{\Delta x}}\\
f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x }=\\
\large \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }\frac{(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{x+\Delta x}{\Delta x}}-(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{x}{\Delta x}}}{\Delta x }=\\
\large \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }\frac{(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{x}{\Delta x}}((1+\Delta x)^{\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x}}-1)}{\Delta x }=\\
\large \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }\frac{(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{x}{\Delta x}}((1+\Delta x)^1-1)}{\Delta x }=\\
\large \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }\frac{(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{x}{\Delta x}}((\Delta x)}{\Delta x }=\\
\large \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 }(1+\Delta x)^{\frac{x}{\Delta x}}=\\e^x}$$
And now, my question is about other way or ways to show this fact ...
It is very interesting if there was a visual proof ...
Is there any idea to show $(\exp(x))'=\exp(x)$
Thanks in advanced .

Comment: I was going to downvote because it seemed that the answers would inevitably be circular, but thinking about it I realized there is indeed [a very nice visual demonstration of this fact](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2096791/276406).  So +1.

Comment: Radius of convergence is $\infty $ in $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+...$

Comment: Not a big fan of a question like "in how many ways can we prove something." In that exact formulation, it is clearly not a mathematics question. I would also like to point out that $f' = f$ can be given as the DEFINITION of the exponential function (with the additional condition $f(0)=1$) - if you take this as definition, then you have nothing to prove.

Comment: In [THIS ARTICLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Characterizations), there are five (5) characterizations of the exponential function.   It is easy to show from any of these that $\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$.

Comment: The second approach you have given is incorrect. The procedure should use a repeated limit and not just a single limit of the form $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **ATTENTION:** No cucumbers were harmed in the making of the graphics!

Here's a proof that I thought was kind of fun:

You can try this experiment to prove $(e^x)'=e^x$.

**Materials:**

1. A cucumber
2. A knife
3. A cutting board
4. An almost infinite amount of time

---

Place the cucumber on the cutting board and assume its radius to be $1$ unit in length. Now, using the knife, make a small incision approximately $45^{\circ}$.
[image: Diagram]

Now, continue cutting and making the cut longer and longer as you rotate the cucumber counter-clockwise (on its axis) and tilting the knife of the blade backwards while keeping the guard of the knife at the edge of the board.
[image: Diagram]

The carves a somewhat accurate representation of the graph of the exponential curve, in cylindrical coordinates: $y=\exp\theta$.
[image: Diagram]

Define the $x$ axis to be the bottom of the cucumber and the $y$ axis to be the central line *through* the cucumber.

[image: Diagram]

If you change the perpendicular view, and draw an imaginary tangent line (or you can draw an actual one. Just be careful though!), the curve intersects the $y$ axis at different heights. *However*, the tangent will *always* intersect the $x$ axis at the same point. Thus,

$$(e^x)'=\dfrac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\dfrac {e^\theta-0}{0+1}=e^\theta$$

Comment: Cool! (As you'd expect from a cucumber-based answer.)  But shouldn't it come with a disclaimer that no cucumbers were actually harmed during the preparation of your graphic?  $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @RobArthan See my new edit! :D :D :)

Comment: What software did you use to produce these pictures ?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can show this visually.**

I don't know if this could be called a *proof,* strictly speaking, but it will indeed show it visually.

Choose **any** point on the graph of $y=e^x$.  Mark that point.  (Call it point $B$.)

Now mark the point on the $x$ axis with the same $x$ coordinate as point $B$.  (Call it point $C$.)

Now mark the point on the $x$ axis one unit to the left of point $C$.  Call this point $A$.

Draw a line from point $A$ to point $B$.

The line will be exactly tangent to the graph of $y=e^x$ at point $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completion of [the idea given by Wildcard](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2096791/276406), turning the visual demonstration into a proof.

We claim that for any $x_0$, the line 
$$y(x)=e^{x_0}(x-(x_0-1))$$
 is tangent to $e^x$ at $x_0$. This tells us, as Wildcard suggested, that the derivative of $e^x$ at $x_0$ is the slope $e^{x_0}$.

To see that this line is tangent, it suffices to show because $e^x$ is concave (a whole other story), that $y(x)\leq e^x$ for every $x$.

First note that $e^x=e^{x_0}e^{x-x_0}$, and since
 $$x-(x_0-1)=1+(x-x_0)\leq e^{x-x_0},$$
 It follows that $$y(x)\leq e^x,$$

completing our proof.